# How does a browser force loading non-cached data in the request header?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

I'm building a little application that loads fresh data from the OpenStreetMap project. For my app, it's very important to request the freshest data possible, so I don't want to be served cached data. Now, since OpenStreetMap has a lot of data requests to handle, they have some kind of caching on their side too. Simply sending a GET request isn't enough, because this will likely serve a pre-cached tile:

```
x-served-by: cache-ams21054-AMS
x-cache: HIT
x-cache-hits: 1
x-timer: S1652643221.620976,VS0,VE1
```

This led me to inspect the requests sent by Firefox on the official website. This is the header that is sent on a normal refresh:

```
Host: tile.openstreetmap.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.openstreetmap.org/
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

And this is the request sent on a force-refresh (ctrl+f5):

```
GET /14/8033/6198.png HTTP/2
Host: tile.openstreetmap.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.openstreetmap.org/
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The only two additional header fields are `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache`.

This led me to implement the same in my own application. I added the same header fields to my requests. *However*, this did not fix my problem and I was still getting served cached content (`x-cache: HIT`) in the response. After some googling and experimenting, I tried adding `max-age=0` to `Cache-Control` and this did stop the servers from sending me cached content.

**Here's my question**: how come that *my* app needs the `max-age=0` value, while a browser can get non-cached content reliably with just the `no-cache` values?

What other fields control that behavior, if all the fields I have are these:

```
User-Agent: MyApp-v1
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

---

For reference, here are the response headers for a standard refresh and a force-refresh:

Refresh:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
expect-ct: max-age=0
etag: "afa1fdc623f5ea600b40ebd27c27f97a"
cache-control: max-age=33407, stale-while-revalidate=604800, stale-if-error=604800
expires: Thu, 12 May 2022 16:47:46 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-tilerender: odin.openstreetmap.org
content-type: image/png
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Sun, 15 May 2022 20:01:23 GMT
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 304223
x-served-by: cache-ams21051-AMS
x-cache: HIT
x-cache-hits: 1
x-timer: S1652644883.024001,VS0,VE1
content-length: 8290
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Forced refresh:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
expect-ct: max-age=0
etag: "1e2555621fd6e9da0c35d0ab5440d2e5"
cache-control: max-age=8170, stale-while-revalidate=604800, stale-if-error=604800
expires: Sun, 15 May 2022 22:03:15 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-tilerender: nidhogg.openstreetmap.org
content-type: image/png
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Sun, 15 May 2022 19:47:05 GMT
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 0
x-served-by: cache-ams21083-AMS
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1652644026.595670,VS0,VE97
content-length: 14499
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Answer (score 0):

A server can emit data however it wishes, including from its own caches. The `Cache-Control: no-cache` mostly pertain to the browser-side caches.

For a browser to do a 'fresh' request, the most important this is mainly just *not* sending an `ETag` or `If-Modified-Since` header.

There's no standard header/instruction to tell a server to get a 'fresher' version of an item and not use its own internal caches. It's possible that for the API you're using they *do* have a mechanism to request uncached responses, but it's not standard.